# Do I need to insulate between duct and flat roof?

Tags: insulation

I have a flat roof with 2x12 joists. The bays used to be insulated and had an air gap above the insulation that connected to small soffits on both sides of the house.

In one of the bays I now have a makeup air return taking up all but 2-3" of the bay height. It runs about 6 feet and then elbows down into the top of a cabinet where the DC-powered damper opens.

The other end of the bay was closed off with spray foam on the decking and joists, with blown insulation below, but the insulation contractor didn’t fill this 2-3” space above the duct, so it’s basically a closed off air volume between a makeup air duct and the roof.

I’m looking for any suggestions about what to do to keep the roof from molding and rotting here. Do I need some sort of powered fan to exhaust that space? I do have DC power nearby.

Here's a challenging picture of the space, you're looking down the bay along the top of the duct, the roof is above.

[image]

Comment: I removed the part about being annoyed at the contractor - that's purely a matter of opinion and that's off-topic.

Comment: So the soffits are now no longer supplying any cold air under the roof sheathing?  If so, I am not sure this was wise, but I am unfamiliar with how moving the thermal envelope to the roof works.  Are you in a cold weather place, that could experience ice dams?

Comment: @FreeMan I'm not totally sure why that was off-topic. Is there a different community where I can ask if my contractor has done something properly?

Comment: @EvilElf It's no longer to code to install flat roofs in the way it was done in 1959. Now the entire surface except for this small 6 foot chunk is coated in 3-4" of a rigid spray foam insulation and the soffits have been all closed off. The rest of the space between the spray foam and the ceiling sheetrock is BIBS blown insulation. This prevents condensation from forming on the wood, and is the modern solution. The issue is that they didn't do that here, and now I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I would think that duct could warm that air then condensate against the roof sheathing.

Comment: [IRC R806.5](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch08_SecR806.5) is the relevant code. Your installation seems conformant with R806.5 because there's no insulation. The question, then, is whether insulation is required. Certainly your region has minimum insulation standards and your installation doesn't conform to these. I suspect that 3" of spray foam is still nonconformant, so I don't know if you want to involve a building official if this is a dispute with a contractor.

Comment: @popham It's not a dispute, and it's a renovation, so they're doing the best that they can given what we have to work with. The inspectors are quite liberal and happy with basically anything. It has passed its insulation inspection as is. I'm more curious if it would be physically possible to have done something above the space to simulate 806.5.5.1.1 even without meeting the R requirements, to prevent moisture from contacting the wood.

Comment: @EvilElf I would think so too, which is why I'm trying to figure out what the best approach to dealing with this situation is.

Comment: @Luke, stacking panels of closed cell foam could have done it. Maybe for an R value of 20. I think you just have to seal along the edge where it touches the joists. Can't you still put some kind of construction paper on top of the duct and spray insulating foam up there? If you draped it down the sides, you could fill the whole cavity around the duct, no?

Comment: @popham From what I can tell, the duct takes up the entire width of the bay. I have been told by my GC that the closed cell foam expands to quickly and they can't control it well enough given the space in there and it would compress and damage the ductwork. I think they are going to fill that space with rockwool, with inspector approval. I don't feel super comfortable with that... it seems like a good way to promote moisture transfer, but I really haven't been given any other options. They say leaving it empty is the worst option.

Comment: @Luke, once there's the tiniest scrap of insulation in there (as required), then you should go back to that IRC link. It imposes all sorts of constraints on the insulation. I suggested the sprayed foam because it seems feasible to sneak around the duct. If they can sneak Rockwood up there, then can they alternatively sneak in extruded panels?

Comment: @popham The inspector has already signed off on their plan, both for retrofitting the existing bays with foam+BIBS and filling this with rockwool. Code isn't going to be some sort of leverage for me here. I don't know what an extruded panel is, do you mean one of those rigid foam products that they cut? Will that be better than the rockwool?

Comment: @Luke, if you've seen pink insulation panels labeled "XPS," the "X" is for "extruded." It's just a method for manufacturing closed cell foam insulation panels. EPS is also closed cell foam and with similarly good insulation characteristics. The closed cell foam panels, like the spray foam insulation you have elsewhere, falls under the "air impermeable" category from that IRC link. The rockwool falls under the "air permeable" category from that IRC link. Sorry about your inspector situation. Happens all the time, if that makes you feel any better.

Comment: @Luke, see [IRC R1101.7](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-11-re-energy-efficiency#IRC2021P2_Pt04_Ch11_SecN1101.7) for climate zone if you haven't already figured it out.